# Where should setState be called/should it?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a custom navigation bar and am controlling what is being displayed with `_current`, when I update _current, I don't run setState as nothing is being changed on the display (I think this is the correct logic? The square that is displayed is then supposed to be picked out of the array. The code below is what I have, Is this a setState issue or something else?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomNavState createState() => _CustomNavState();
}

class _CustomNavState extends State<CustomNav> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    int _current = 1;

    List<Widget> pages = [
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
      )
    ];

    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: width,
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          pages[_current],
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _current = 0;
                print({_current});
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _current = 1;
                print({_current});
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _current = 2;
                print({_current});
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add `_current` inside `build` method. in fact you should try not to add anything in build method.
take out `_current` from build method. then, if `_current` has effect on UI components, when you are updating it, you must put it in `setState`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change your `_current` you need to call the `setState`. That's because you need to notify the `CustomNav` widget that he need to rebuilt itself.